# How could i use script tag in render part with react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-redux

I want to use this script in return phase in react which this script came from https://www.omise.co/card-js-api

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.omise.co/card.js"


      data-key="YOUR_PUBLIC_KEY"
      data-image="PATH_TO_LOGO_IMAGE"
      data-frame-label="Merchant site name"
      data-button-label="Pay now"
      data-submit-label="Submit"
      data-location="yes"
      data-amount="10025"
      data-currency="thb"

      />
```

but it seems not working at all

Answer (score 0):

Javascript must be inserted in betweeen the `<script>` and `</script>` tag.

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.omise.co/card.js"


      data-key="YOUR_PUBLIC_KEY"
      data-image="PATH_TO_LOGO_IMAGE"
      data-frame-label="Merchant site name"
      data-button-label="Pay now"
      data-submit-label="Submit"
      data-location="yes"
      data-amount="10025"
      data-currency="thb"
>
</script>
```

Self closing tag is not applicable as far as I am concerned.

This should give you a good reference - [Why don't self-closing script tags work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69913/why-dont-self-closing-script-tags-work)

Answer (score 0):

Use template strings with React

```
var script = `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.omise.co/card.js"
      data-key="YOUR_PUBLIC_KEY"
      data-image="PATH_TO_LOGO_IMAGE"
      data-frame-label="Merchant site name"
      data-button-label="Pay now"
      data-submit-label="Submit"
      data-location="yes"
      data-amount="10025"
      data-currency="thb"></script>`;

document.body.appendChild(script);
```